# SSH Tunnel to IPv6

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, ipv6, tunnel, ipv4

At our office we still don't have an IPv6 connection, I do however have one at home, with a Raspberry Pi (installed Raspbian) that has IPv6 connectivity.

Is there an easy way that I can setup a tunnel between my Windows 10 machine and the Raspberry, so I can browse the net via IPv6 (tunneled) ?

SSH on the Raspberry is reachable via ipv4::30001

Comment: SSH is probably not the right tool for what you need. An OpenVPN layer-2 tunnel bridged to your LAN would probably work best. If you have routed a block of IPv6 addresses to the Pi then a layer-3 tunnel is even better.

Comment: @SanderSteffann Do you know of an easy solution? The Pi has a /64 normal home connection

Comment: If you only have one /64 (you should have more, one is almost never enough) then your only option is to bridge your LAN with a layer-2 tunnel and make the VPN client part of the LAN.